# .ajax() method is not working

Tags: jquery

i am new to Jquery and ajax,  wrote a simple jsp page which will show the text on each onkeyup event, the request made by ajax will go through AjaxServlet . i am not getting output with .ajax() method while if i use plain ajax using XhtmlRequest it gives the output.
please as sson as possible

*******JSP Page******************

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function showName(str){



        $.ajax({
              url: '/AjaxServlet',
              type: 'GET',
               data: 'name='+name,
              success: function(response){
               $("#showName").html(response);

                  }

        });



}
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" onkeyup="showName(this.value)">Enter your name</input>
<p>Suggestions: <span id="showName"></span></p> 

</body>
</html>
```

*****AjaxServlet*******************

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name=request.getParameter("name");
        response.setContentType("text/xml");
        PrintWriter responseWriter=response.getWriter();
        responseWriter.write("Welcome "+name);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Where is your jQuery library?  Have you forgotten to download and include it in the HTML page?

Answer (score 2):

is 'name' actually the correct thing to use? the function is `showName(str)`?

try the following:

```
    $.ajax({
          url: '/AjaxServlet',
          type: 'GET',
          data: {name:str}, // use a object literal here
          success: function(response){
             $("#showName").html(response);
          },
          error: function(xhr, status, error){

             alert("help I died! [" + status + "] [" + error +"]" ); 
          }
    });


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws  ServletException, IOException {
    String name=request.getParameter("name");
    // your output isn't xml! ... use text/plain in stead
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    PrintWriter responseWriter=response.getWriter();
    responseWriter.write("Welcome "+name);

}
```

Comment: Hi Gareth Davis,

thanks for rpl..i included the jquery lib and tried the above code but its not working...even not showing any error alert ..

Comment: oh i am getting error alert now....alert msg is..

""help i died! [object Object]""

now wer is the problem??

Comment: is there any error output on the browsers error console? (F12 in ie, ctrl+shift=J on firefox and ctrl+shift+I in chrome/safari) Have you tried using the javascript debugger?

Comment: I got it...Thanks...
problem was:  
         i was using url: '/AjaxServlet' 
         instead of  url: 'AjaxServlet'

thank you very much

Comment: I've just updated the error function to print the message...The documentation for jquery is very good and details the error handler parameters here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: cool, good luck with your project and feel free to click that big tick next to the answer :-)

Comment: but it is working in eclipse only..if i use crome/IE/mozilla bowser its not showing anything..not even error alert..

Comment: as a wild stab in the dark, you either haven't included the jqery script, or you have included it with an incorrect path. Add <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js'></script> before your code

Comment: now it is printing "[object XMLHttpRequest]" as response instead of printing name
chrome error-----"Refused to set unsafe header "Connection""

there is no error in moziila....

Comment: ok.. set back a minute and check some basics for me. 1. You app builds and deploys to your app server (tomcat or the like?) 1. the html page you are developing is also served from your app server, ie. from http://localhost:8080/thingy.html or similar and is not from file://your/directory/thingy.html 3. jQuery is present and loaded in the page (test using the javascript console, just type $ if it says 'undefined' then it isn't present.

Comment: i got it finally...thanks Gareth for your time and help..javascript was not loading....now its working fine...thank you very much...;-);-)...